# Find folder contents difference on WIndows 7?

Tags: windows-7, git, batch-file, svn, search-folder

I have a larger folder containing all my SVN files. I got attacked my a virus destroying some files but also corrupting SVN config files, so now TortoiseSVN cannot recognize it as a SVN folder.

I can redownload the repository to other location but there are some files I didn't commit to it.

Is there some software that can tell me difference in contents between folders or should I write a batch script that can tell me which files were not commited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative is WinMerge

http://winmerge.org/?lang=en

"WinMerge is an Open Source differencing and merging tool for Windows. WinMerge can compare both folders and files, presenting differences in a visual text format that is easy to understand and handle."

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to compare 2 directories is using the `TREE` command.

```
TREE  D:\SOURCE /A /F >D:\SOURCE.TXT

TREE  D:\DEST /A /F >D:\DEST.TXT
```

Then use WinDiff or DiffChecker to compare the two text files.

[How to Compare Two Directories And Find Out the Differences?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/compare-two-directories-files-find-differences/)

Answer (score 0):

The Oxygen XML editor package (or Author or Developer packages) offers a [GUI directory diff tool](https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/18/ug-author/topics/directories-comparison.html) that also allows you to easily copy changes from one file tree to another.
A 30-day trial license is free, main site [here](https://www.oxygenxml.com/).  There's also a GUI file diff tool.